# CSRF protection in Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat7, csrf

How can I prevent CSRF protection using Tomcat 7 ?

I have heard that tomcat 7 provides CSRF filter
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/CsrfPreventionFilter.html

But is it thread safe ?

Or shall we do a custom protection in our spring 3 application ?

Answer (score -1):

`CsrfPreventionFilter` is a good way to prevent CSRF attacks, altough it's part of the tomcat code base and is based on putting the token in the URL.

This means the token will be logged etc, it's better to put the token in a hidden field in each form of the page.

Spring security 3.2 will have built-in support, and the solution would also work in other application servers. But depending on your application there is probably no need for building a custom protection at the spring level, the tomcat solution works OK.

The tomcat filter is thread-safe, given that each http request is handled from beginning to end by one thread, and that the token cache has synchronized access.

Comment: For Tomcat, I don't see any token put in the URL